# python преобразовать список

Tags: python, list, telebot, tuple, строки

Подскажите как можно преобразовать список с кортежем в строки не использую for. Наверное и join не подойдет.
Дело в том что мне нужно данный список отправить с помощью телеграм бота, а из списка он отправляет только 1 элемент.
Если преобазовать список в сроку, в телеграмм выглядит коряво, и без переносов.

```
[('10.10.10.11', 'Cisco Inc'), ('10.10.10.12', 'Cisco Inc'), ('10.10.10.13', 'Cisco Inc'), ('10.10.10.14', 'Cisco Inc')]
```

Хочется в телеграмм увидеть следующее

```
10.10.10.11 Cisco Inc
10.10.10.12 Cisco Inc
10.10.10.13 Cisco Inc
10.10.10.14 Cisco Inc
```

Comment: `a` - ваш список, `b` - пустая переменная, `for x in a: b += x[0] + ' ' + x[1] + '\n'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

```
msg = "\n".join(" ".join(x) for x in data)
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
msg = "\n".join(map(" ".join, data))
```

вывод:

```
print(msg)
10.10.10.11 Cisco Inc
10.10.10.12 Cisco Inc
10.10.10.13 Cisco Inc
10.10.10.14 Cisco Inc
```

Answer (score 2):

Коли не нравится `for` можно использовать `while`, чай ведь не в функциональном стиле пишется код, верно?! Да и в отношении `join` поди пойми, что имелось в виду. В противном случае было бы нечто вроде:

```
lst = [('10.10.10.11', 'Cisco Inc'), ..., ('10.10.10.14', 'Cisco Inc')]
lst = list(map(lambda x: ('{} '*len(x)).format(*x), lst))
print(('{}\n'*len(lst)).format(*lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

Простое и быстрое решение через словари:

```
t = [('10.10.10.11', 'Cisco Inc'), 
     ('10.10.10.12', 'Cisco Inc'), 
     ('10.10.10.13', 'Cisco Inc'), 
     ('10.10.10.14', 'Cisco Inc')]

for k,v in dict(t).items():
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]